# Paypal Payment Pro not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to paypal integration.I have just integrate Paypal's direct payment in a asp.net web application using the code provide by paypal.When i click payment button a security exception is generated:

```
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
Source Error: 
Line 121:            Response.Redirect("Paymentform.aspx?fail=1");
Line 122:        }
Line 123:    }
Line 124:
Line 125:    protected void Populate1()
```

The site is hosted by godaddy.
    Can anyone tell me what is the solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the application is running with partial trust, which is typical for shared hosting. Ask your host to allow full-trust to your application (good luck with that), or change hosts (next time, make it a point to look for full-trust listed in features), or go dedicated-server/vps hosting (because you'd be able to control that setting then), or use a different paypal method to integrate with them (that doesn't involve using paypal libs or whatever it is that you're doing; you have payment methods that involve redirecting users to paypal to complete the transaction, without ever touching the credit card info). Sorry I can't suggest more constructive ideas, and sorry for the sarcasm (if you feel it).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that your application is running in partial trust level 
once you try this in config file

```
<system.web>
<trust level = "Full" />
</system.web>
```

if this doesn't solve your problem then contact your hosting person if they can give full trust 
otherwise change hosting.

If you are using dedicated server you can change trust level but your application is on shared server so it is up to your hosting provider.